# AlarmManager or CalendarProvider, What should be used for an app like Keep or Evernote?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-calendar, repeatingalarm

I am developing an android application just like Google Keep and Evernote. Now I want to add many reminders or alarms one time and repeated too. I have both options and I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem some time back. The answer to your question depends on two things:

**1.** How much time do you have ?

**2.** How comfortable are you with `ContentProvider`s generally ?

There are three ways you can approach this problem:

**1.** Use `AlarmManger` and `Service` and roll your own `SQLite` db. This is the fastest & easiest way.

**2.** Use `CalendarProvider` which will make use of its own internal `Service`s & database mechanisms. This will require a valid Google Account belonging to the user, and moreover the user can also create / modify / delete alarms independent of your app.

**3.** Create a custom `ContentProvider` with its own internal `Service`s and its own `SQLite` db for `CRUD` operations. This is the most complex and most time-consuming approach, but you will learn a great deal. The advantage of this approach (besides the knowledge gained) is that a `ContentProvider` can share its data with other apps on the phone through a well-defined interface.

Comment: Well, I have no problem in learning. I have used AlarmManager+Service in a recent app and saved all Intents to DB with my TaskID etc. That seems good. But I was wondering might be saving too many like 1 thousand reminders and alarms will be too heavy? My Requirement is something like that.

Comment: I dont think it will be a problem saving any number of reminders/alarms, one thousand or one million. After all they are just plain Java objects, right ? Even a million objects might take up no more than a few hundred kilobytes at most, as long as you are not saving anything like images or videos along with the object :)

Comment: If you do decide to create a custom `ContentProvider`, it will be very good, but a big challenge. I wish you good luck :)

Comment: I will mark it as the correct. Let give other people chance. Might be someone comes with more details and a sound proof of what to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

`AlarmManager` is for cases where you want to get control to do something at a future time, such as use a `Notification` for an event reminder.

`CalendarProvider` is for cases where you want to add something to the user's calendar (e.g., Google Calendar on most Android devices). You do not get control, the user can delete event, etc.

Comment: I dont think so. You can create you own calendar using CalendarProvider.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch: It is still the *user's* calendar. And you *still* do not get control at the points in time -- at most, the user's calendar application may remind them.

Comment: You mean we can't make them private or hide from the default calendar application?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch: That is up to the device's calendar app, not you. There are thousands of Android devices, and I would be surprised if they all used the same calendar app.